# DelayCompress in logback

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logback, filebeat

Do we have delaycompress on rotation feature in logback like logrotate has? I googled but unable to find any. Thought of asking it here.

My use case:

I am trying to setup ELK for my project which uses filebeat so send the logs to logstash. In my logback config I have a rolling policy on size (500 mb) after which it rolls the file into compressed gz format. Issue with filebeat is that it doesn't support gz format and if the files get rollover there are chances of few lines getting missed. So if we have delaycompress feature which will delay the compression until next rotation like logrotate does I think I can achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance